# Key bindings are all messed up when using a vncserver running vscode remotely

Tags: vscode-keybinding

Many of my keys are mapped incorrectly when accessing vscode through a vncserver (working on mac, operating vscode on a linux server).  Keys are mapped fine when using Remote Development. The key mapping issue is specific to VSCode... no other software is affected. I've been plagued  by this issue for awhile and can not figure out how to fix it... very surprised I haven't found anything through googling.

The first place I look to fix the issue is in the keybindings but even there I have issues. When I try to modify a keybinding the keys are all mixed up: backspace => [unknown], esc => f2, return +> f1, space => 7

Here's what I see when a press backspace, esc, return , and space space in that order when trying to provide new keybindings:

https://www.veed.io/view/e051a0a9-1ecf-4dea-9093-522cea930452?sharingWidget=true&panel=share

Does anyone know a fix for this?